# Check database for changes via long polling

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, chat, long-polling

Im creating a chat app in ASP.NET MVC3.
im using long polling and AsyncController to do so

when a user posts a chat its saved in database , to retrieve should i constantly check database for change in record or after definite interval
or is there an better/ efficient way of doing it

i came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595450/checking-mysql-for-long-polling-purposes) but could not get a usable answer.

Answer (score 4):

You may take a look at [SignalR](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx) for an efficient way. Contrary to the standard polling mechanism (in which you are sending requests at regular intervals to check for changes), SignalR uses a push mechanism in which the server sends notifications to connected clients to notify them about changes.

Comment: i Find implimenting SignalR well.. HARD . and i read that signalr also uses long poll and changes to web sockets when available .

Comment: @deepakgates, SignalR implements this in an optimized way. If you find it hard you could stick to traditional polling mechanism then.

Comment: which goes back to my question what shuld I do with checking time interval.. also please share if u came across any good tutorial of signalr which involvs database interaction

Comment: @deepakgates, you could use the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) javascript function to execute AJAX requests at regular intervals to a controller action which will check for changes. As far as SignalR tutorials are concerned, I think that the [documentation](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki) contains enough examples to get you started. If you need to learn database interaction you may take a look at ADO.NET tutorials as this has nothing to do with SignalR or ASP.NET. So get started, and if you encounter some specific problems don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: thanks ill look into SignalR Documentation. but i think i did not make myself clear. im long polling to a async controller for lets say 60 sec. Now in method i need to check for new records in database how shuld that be done. every second or 30 sec interval or so

Comment: @deepakgates, what do you mean by *polling for 60 seconds*? How does your controller action look like?

Comment: i meant action has a timeout of 60 seconds after which it return empty (as there were no new records in database) and a new 60 sec poll will start again. i have not written action yet

Comment: @deepakgates, timeout in action? You mean like a Thread.Sleep? If this is what you intend to do please never do it.

Comment: My apologies if i cant make it clear , im new to long polling and async controllers . take a look here http://jacob4u2.posterous.com/mvc-3-long-polling-comet-chat-example im trying to do somthing like this

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using long polling and an asynccontrolller, why not create a message pool? Take a look at [this solution](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2011/04/12/roll-your-own-mvc-3-long-polling-chat-site/).

In a nutshell, instead of just writing the updated chat to the database, you should also stick it in some sort of queue. Then each user's async thread is listening to that pool waiting for a message to appear. When one appears return the data to the user through your normal operation. When all listening threads have picked up the message it can be removed from the queue. This will prevent you from having several threads hammering your database looking for a new message.

Comment: actuall i already know about that and i selected long polling and asunccontroller because of that example.. but only modification i want is to save in database

Comment: You can still save in a database, but for updating your clients use a message queue.  Post the message to each user in the queue using your long polling example and also save the message to a database. - If you're asking how you should be organizing the database to save the messages, you're asking another question :)

Comment: What if a different process, one that does not have access to the message queue, is changing the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can give PServiceBus(http://pservicebus.codeplex.com/) a try and here is a sample web chat app(http://74.208.226.12/ChatApp/chat.html) running and does not need database in between to pass message between two web clients. If you want to persist data in the database for logging sake, you can always subscribe to the chat message and log it to database.